# autocomplete with labels defined by user commands

Tags: macros, texstudio, auto-completion

I use a command that automatically generates labels to include pictures:

```
\newcommand{\plot}[3]{

    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[#2]{Fig/#1}
        \caption{#3}
        \label{fig:#1}
    \end{figure}
}
```

How could I make texstudio autocomplete suggest the labels generated by the command?

I created a simple myDefs.cwl:

```
\plot{label}#l  
\figref{label}#r
```

Which works with:

```
\plot{abc}{width=\columnwidth}{caption}
\figref{abc}
```

but how could I make label "fig:abc" to appear among suggestions to keep figures separate?

Comment: You can create a custom `.cwl` file and specify what the auto completion should suggest. See http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION for details.

Comment: note that you should not use `\center`  (that is the internal form of `\begin{center}` it should be `\centering` also `[h!]` is usually wrong and latex will generate a warning and change it to `[ht]` but in most cases `[htp]` is better (not including `p` makes it far more likely that the figure goes to the end of the document)

Comment: Thanks for reference and suggestions! How could one issue a label different from arg1 for auto-completion though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. There is no way to complete to strings other than the ones given as the label argument.

I suggest to use explicit labels everywhere. This is also more clear to the reader.

```
\plot{fig:abc}{width=\columnwidth}{caption}
\figref{fig:abc}
```

And since you'll have completion then, it's not too much effort.

Comment: Thanks, but how to use file "abc", if  the argument of plot is "fig:abc" in that case?

Comment: There`s no easy solution. Either have two explicit arguments for label and filename, or use the same name for label and filename.